# Xcode App Simulates and Launches Black Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

When I launch my iOS app it seems that I only get a black screen on both device and simulator. I'm running Xcode 4.4.1 and the iOS sim is set up for 5.1. Is there any information you can give to help me out here? I'm pretty sure it's the viewController, but I'm not sure.

No background image
No change in colors
Basic App (Text boxes/Ad Bar/Nav Bar/Table Cells)
- All objects are available in Xcode (haven't messed with the coding yet)

screen cap img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGOhT.jpg

Code to come!

Comment: You will need to provide more details about your project setup before anyone can reasonably help you.  Was this project working at some point?  Is it a basic demo project that launches with a black screen?  How did you create the project?

Comment: Created with base storyboard on Xcode for iPhone, used basic objects and just dragged and dropped on the template to try and learn a bit more about Xcode. Worked briefly in the beginning, but now it only opens the launch screen, the as the app loads it goes black.

Comment: You have not provided any information on your app.  There is no way we can provide assistance unless you post code.  Have you tried stepping through your code using the debugger to ensure everything is working as you expect?

Comment: Img link above. Posting code asap.

Just ran through with the debugger again. Says that I need to designate an entry point. Debugger text here:

2012-08-08 16:53:35.728 RPC[5135:f803] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard_iPhone' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
(lldb) 

How do? Also, thanks for the help guys. Super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this app all morning and I think I figured out my problem. So it turns out the problem was the "Ad BannerView" that I had put on the main View. Deleted it and it simulates just fine.

Not sure what caused it to do that, and if anyone knows, I'd very much appreciate a little bit more learning.

If you guys have anymore advice for me on here or in Xcode I'd love to hear it.

Thanks a ton for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

i Know i am late but i am posting it, If it could help someone else.

You may probably removed your initial viewController, You can set it by followed

1. Go to main storyboard
2. select viewController you want to show up first
3. in attributing inspector you will see "Is Initial ViewController" with a checkbox
4. mark is checked(tick sign) and give it a run.

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide image for that the size of image for iPhone should be 320,480 and 640 , 960 with name Default.png , Defauld@2x.png , and image should on root of aproject.
or you can select your image form XCode.
[image: select Projecte launch image and icon]

Comment: Thanks, but I've got the launch screen down. My problem is the app itself after the launch. What is some info I can give to help you guys help me?

Comment: Tell us which basic template did you use, what did you do with the code, and with the interface builder (eg. with storyboard) and when did the problem start?